# *http.http2gzipReader vs io.ReadCloser Golang

Tags: http, go, glide-golang

In the defination of the source code of response.go it is defined that the Body of type `io.ReadCloser` but while printing the type of Body by the following code it prints `*http.http2gzipReader`. Are they both same?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    //any url
    url := "https://www.goal.com/en-in"
    res, _ := http.Get(url)
    body := res.Body
    fmt.Printf("tpye is %T", body)
}
```

Comment: "Are they both same?" No they are not, however `*http.http2gzipReader` implements `io.ReadCloser` and because of that it can be use as such.

Comment: See https://tour.golang.org/methods/9 and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types for more info on interfaces.

Comment: @mkopriva why the response.Body type is *http.http2gzipReader instead of io.ReadCloser? Can you share some resourses?

Comment: It's declared as an interface type so that more than just one concrete implementation can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not same.

`io.ReadCloser` interface is the type of request body but the `*http.http2gzipReader` is the concrete type assigned to the interface. That's what we call, `*http.http2gzipReader` implements `io.ReadCloser` interface.